# App update Notifications in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I developed an app using codename one,and in that app i need to show notifications to user regarding the app update if update is available in playstore.LocationManger is working on mobiles with version 5 and above,but its not working on tablets.How to work with notifications in android/ios tablets with version using codename one.

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to Location Manager?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to differenciate local notification (which is launched when app is running or in background) and push notification (which use Google or Apple server). 
I suggest you to use a webservice and push notification. For example, when your app launch, request the webservice to send the app version and know the current version on stores. Here, you can deduce if the app can be updated and you can send push notification to alert that an update is avalaible.
Codename One provides an easy-to-use API for push notification.  
However, Google Play and ITunes usually alert user that updates are avalaible.